# Could not find a part of the path Xamarin Android C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, filestream, xamarin.android

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using ExcelDataReader;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace App3
{
    public class DatabaseInteraction
    {
        string dbFilePath;
        int tabFactor;
        public DatabaseInteraction(string dataBaseFile, int tabFactor) { this.dbFilePath = dataBaseFile;this.tabFactor = tabFactor; }
        public void check()
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dbFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);
                DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
                var row = result.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                var str = (string)row[0];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка в FileStream:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path  "/‪C:/test1.xlsx".

Сразу скажу, файл на месте, много находил информации по этому поводу ничего не помогло. Не понимаю в чем проблема, еще меня смущает "/" вначале пути в тексте ошибки "/‪C:/test1.xlsx", может ошибка из за этого "/" вначале, хотя в FileStream передается обыкновенный путь "C:/test1.xlsx", возможно это связано с Xamarin, путь до файла писал по разному и с @ и с двойным слешем, c этими символами вообще была ошибка, что файл не найден, хотя проверял что он там есть.

Comment: Прочитайте эту [статью](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/platform/files/).

Comment: В androide не может быть диска C. Ваш файл на компьютере наверное, а не на устройстве.